# How to share a file from initContainer to base container in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a custom **alpine** image (alpine-audit) which includes a *jar* file in the ***/tmp*** directory. What I need is to use that alpine-audit image as the **initContainers** base image and copy that *jar* file that I've included, to a location where the Pod container can access.

My yaml file is like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: init-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: my.private-artifactory.com/audit/alpine-audit:0.1.0
    command: ['cp', '/tmp/auditlogger-1.0.0.jar', 'auditlogger-1.0.0.jar']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: "/tmp"
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
  - name: workdir
    emptyDir: {}
```

I think there is some mistake in the `command` line.
I assumed *initContainer* copy that jar file to *emptyDir* then the nginx based container can access that jar file using the *mountPath*.
But it does not even create the Pod. Can someone point me where it has gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are mouting a volume to a directory in pod, that directory have only content of the volume. If you are mounting `emptyDir` into your `alpine-audit:0.1.0` the /tmp directory becomes empty. I would mount that volume on some other dir, like `/app`, then copy the `.jar` from /tmp to /app.

The container is not starting probably because the initContainer failes running  the command.

Try this configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: init-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: my.private-artifactory.com/audit/alpine-audit:0.1.0
    command: ['cp', '/tmp/auditlogger-1.0.0.jar', '/app/auditlogger-1.0.0.jar'] # <--- copy from /tmp to new mounted EmptyDir
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: "/app" # <-- change the mount path not to overwrite your .jar
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
  - name: workdir
    emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Wonder how this working, as volume mounts can be read only with this change -
> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/58720