# copy directory from initContainer to various paths via volumes

Tags: docker-compose

Context:
I have the image init_app with some directory '/build' which i want to share with main container app and put content to 2 different paths.

Issue: init_app doesn't want to be up. I've got this errors.

`cp: can't create '/static/favicon.ico': No such file or directory cp: can't create directory '/static/fonts': No such file or directory`

partial values.yaml config below

```yaml
    containers:
      app:
        image: some_server_image:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: static-stash
            mountPath: /opt/nginx/html/site1
          - name: static-stash
            mountPath: /opt/nginx/html/site2
        resources:
          limits: { memory: "2.5Gi", cpu: "1" }
          requests: { memory: "500Mi", cpu: "0.2" }
        command: [ 'bash','-c','start_server.sh' ]
    initContainers:
      init_app:
        image: init_app:latest
        volumeMounts:
          - name: static-stash
            mountPath: /static
        resources:
          limits: { memory: "180Mi", cpu: "0.2" }
          requests: { memory: "150Mi", cpu: "0.1" }
        command: [ "sh", "-c", "cp -r /build/* /static/" ]
```

The aforementioned config I've made using [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/) from official k8s site.

Help :)) i've lost a lot of hours on it.  How to share folders/files properly?

I have the working example in docker-compose which can explain what I want to do

```yaml
  app:
    image: some_server_image:latest
    volumes:
      - "static-stash:/opt/nginx/html/site1"
      - "static-stash:/opt/nginx/html/site2"
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    command: [ 'bash','-c','start-server.sh' ]
    depends_on:
      - init_app
  init_app:
    image: init_app:latest
    volumes:
      - "static-stash:/static/"
    entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "cp -r /build/* /static/" ]
    restart: "no"
volumes:
  static-stash:
```

another similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896875/how-to-share-a-file-from-initcontainer-to-base-container-in-kubernetes) didn't help me

Comment: why are you doing this at runtime with an init container? Why not simply put the files into the image at build time?

Comment: if your concern is not to have the whole build image in the prod image, look into the multi-stage build image process (use a build image, build the code, then use a from base image and use COPY from build image to move the files to your final image

Comment: if your volume an emptyDir?

Comment: yeah, main app is nginx&kong(api-gateway). i have to copy static to nginx server.

volume is emptyDir
    volumes:
      - name: static-stash
        emptyDir: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for everyone who participated.

I'm noob. I did't mentioned that we use helm and there are some templates.
People from DevExp finally have told me how to transform my code into that i mentioned in first message. Actually problem wasn't in syntaxis. Syntaxis was correct, if you use immaculate K8s

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).